# how does Increment and Decrement work in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain why this function returns `0`?

Shouldn't it return `1` since `n++ = n` and `--n = n-1`?

```
var x = function(n) {
    return n++ - --n;
};
```

Comment: `--n` is `(n + 1) - 1` (the original `n`), which is `n`, not `n - 1`. `n` changed at `n++`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n++` is a [*post*-increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment), so first return the value, then will add `1` to it:

```js
var n = 1;

console.log(n++); //shows 1, increments `n` to 2
console.log(n);//shows 2
console.log(n++); //shows 2, increments `n` to 3
```

`--n` is a [*pre*-decrement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement) - the value is first reduced by `1` and then return

```js
var n = 3;

console.log(--n); //shows 2, `n` is already set to 2
console.log(n);//shows 2
console.log(--n); //shows 1, `n` is already set to 1
```

Here is an example to explain how this is being evaluated: When it's being evaluated:

```js
var x = function (n) {
  return n++ - --n;
};

x(5);
```

0. First `n = 5` we go from there:

```
n = 5

n++ - --n
```

1. The post-increment has the [highest precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) here, so we start with that.

2.`n++` will return `5` but also *change* `n` to `6`. So if we resolve that we have:

```
n = 6

5 - --n
```

3. Next in the order of precedence is the the pre-decrement operation.

4. `--n` will *reduce* `n` and return the new value, so:

```
n = 5

5 - 5
```

5. Finally, we solve the subtraction and get `0`.

Answer (score 2):

n++ - --n

if n = 10, then the value of (n++) is 10, but after that n is increased by one.
So n = 11 after evaluating (n++). if n = 11, (--n) = 10.

```js
n++   -    --n
--- -----  ---
10  n = 11 10
```

so the result is 0

Answer (score 1):

This is a left to right evaluation and the incrementation is done after its value is used.
So lets assume the input is 10
Evaluate to 10 then increase then decrease so 10 - 10 the final expression.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `n = 10`
 1. `n++` will return the original value that `n` held before being incremented. And before going to the next operation `n` will be 11.
 2. `--n` will decrease **increased value(11)** by 1, and then return the decreased value.
 3. Finally, 10 - 10 is 0

[Arithmetic Operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment)